# How to implement a view that can show text and a replace text with vector image depending on what's in the text

Tags: android, image, android-studio, view

I'm retrieving text from an API where I wish to replace text in arbitrary places with a small vector image.

Example :

*When you roll "6" add 3 coins to your bag.*

In the above example, I would like to try to replace the world "coins" with a vector image.

I'm unsure if there is a way to manipulate a built in view, or if I need to create a custom view or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use an ImageSpan in your text.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan

You'd need to parse the text yourself and do the replacement of course, but that will allow you to display an inline image.